# how to calculate data multiplication by index, not by number

Tags: angularjs

I get this kind of problem

```
$scope.quantity = 2;
$scope.price = 230000;

$scope.total = function(){
   return $scope.price * $scope.quantity;
}
```

how to make the numbers converted into a certain index, so that the total will be based on the index, not the numbers?

Comment: my data in an array

Comment: can you post your data i.e json object and what you wanna achieve with sample example